# How to compare two groups when there are many outcome variables?

Tags: t-test, multiple-comparisons

Suppose we have two patient groups, healthy and ill patients, and we measure the chemical concentrations of multiple chemicals. Now we want to determine which chemical concentrations are different for the two groups.

**Can we just apply a separate student T-test for each of the chemicals?**

It seems that for a large enough number of chemicals, you will always get a significant result for one of them.

Comment: For one approach, see the [Hotelling T test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling%27s_T-squared_distribution)

Answer (score 2):

This known as a [multiplicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons) problem (a.k.a. alpha-inflation, and many other names).
There are many methods to compensate for the fact you are testing many hypotheses, but first of all, you have to decide what is the measure of error you wish to control for. If you can allow for a proportion of false findings (chemicals found to differ when they actually do not), you should use the [FDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate) measure. The most popular and simple procedure is the Benjamini-Hochberg procedure.
 If you wish to protect yourself from the possibility of **any** false finding, then look into [FWE control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familywise_error_rate). Some general purpose methods of correction are [Bonferroni](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction) and [Holm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holm%E2%80%93Bonferroni_method). 
If you are using R, look into the *p.adjust* function which also has good references.

Comment: +1 This is a good answer.  What makes chemical data different from these general recommendations, though, is that frequently these data are highly intercorrelated: one chemical test may yield a vector of results (concentrations of various analytical parameters), each of which is a slightly different measurement of some related characteristic of the system being measured.  Thus, some multiple-comparisons adjustment is needed, but Bonferroni may be far too strict.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing univariate t-test you can look if your groups are different in multivariate analysis. Take a look at PLS-DA, it was developed for exactly this kind of medical questions and the results can be cross-validated to avoid false findings.